# Kubernetes 1.3.x on AWS gets only one working minion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I'm trying to start a new Kubernetes cluster on AWS with the following settings:

```
export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws

export KUBE_AWS_INSTANCE_PREFIX="k8-update-test"
export KUBE_AWS_ZONE="eu-west-1a"
export AWS_S3_REGION="eu-west-1"

export ENABLE_NODE_AUTOSCALER=true

export NON_MASQUERADE_CIDR="10.140.0.0/20"
export SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE="10.140.1.0/24"
export DNS_SERVER_IP="10.140.1.10"

export MASTER_IP_RANGE="10.140.2.0/24"
export CLUSTER_IP_RANGE="10.140.3.0/24"
```

After running `$KUBE_ROOT/cluster/kube-up.sh` the master appears and 4 (default) minions are started. Unfortunately only one minion gets read. The result of `kubectl get nodes` is:

```
NAME                                         STATUS     AGE
ip-172-20-0-105.eu-west-1.compute.internal   NotReady   19h
ip-172-20-0-106.eu-west-1.compute.internal   NotReady   19h
ip-172-20-0-107.eu-west-1.compute.internal   Ready      19h
ip-172-20-0-108.eu-west-1.compute.internal   NotReady   19h
```

Please not that one node is running while 3 are not ready. If I look at the details of a NotReady node I get the following error:

> ConfigureCBR0 requested, but PodCIDR not set. Will not configure CBR0
>   right now.

If I try to start the cluster with out the settings NON_MASQUERADE_CIDR, SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE, DNS_SERVER_IP, MASTER_IP_RANGE and CLUSTER_IP_RANGE everything works fine. All minions get ready as soon as they are started.

Does anyone has an idea why the PodCIDR was only set on one node but not on the other nodes?

One more thing: The same settings worked fine on kubernetes 1.2.4.

Comment: Try this manually created cbr0 and set --configure-cbr0=false and see if that gets fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Cluster IP range is too small. You've allocated a /24 for your entire cluster (255 addresses), and Kubernetes by default will give a /24 to each node. This means that the first node will be allocated `10.140.3.0/24` and then you won't have any further /24 ranges to allocate to the other nodes in your cluster.

The fact that this worked in 1.2.4 was a bug, because the CIDR allocator wasn't checking that it didn't allocate ranges beyond the cluster ip range (which it now does). Try using a larger range for your cluster (GCE uses a /14 by default, which allows you to scale to 1000 nodes, but you should be fine with a /20 for a small cluster).